# scala aggregate first function giving unexpected results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using a simple groupby query in scala spark where the objective is to get the first value in the group in a sorted dataframe. Here is my spark dataframe

```
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
|ID             |some_flag |some_type  |  Timestamp        |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
|      656565654|      true|     Type 1|2018-08-10 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 1|2017-08-02 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 2|2016-07-30 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 2|2016-05-04 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 2|2016-04-29 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 2|2015-10-29 00:00:00|
|      656565654|     false|     Type 2|2015-04-29 00:00:00|
+---------------+----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Here is my aggregate query

```
val sampleDF = df.sort($"Timestamp".desc).groupBy("ID").agg(first("Timestamp"), first("some_flag"), first("some_type"))
```

The expected result is

```
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
|ID             |some_falg    |some_type|  Timestamp        |
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
|      656565654|         true|   Type 1|2018-08-10 00:00:00|
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
```

But getting following wierd output and it keeps changing like a random row

```
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
|ID             |some_falg    |some_type|  Timestamp        |
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
|      656565654|        false|   Type 2|2015-10-29 00:00:00|
+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Also please note that there are no nulls in the dataframe. I am scratching me head where I am doing something wrong. Need help!

Comment: what is the datatype of `timestamp`?

Comment: timestamp is the datatype of timestamp

Answer (score 3):

The way you are trying to get all the first values returns an incorrect result. Each column value might be from a different row.

Instead you should only `order by` timestamp in the descending order per group and get the first row. An easy way to do it is using a function like `row_number`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val sampleDF = df.withColumn("rnum",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col("ID")).orderBy(col("Timestamp").desc)))

sampleDF.filter(col("rnum") == 1).show
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Vamsi's answer; the problem is that the values in a `groupBy` result group aren't returned in any particular order (particularly given the distributed nature of Spark operations), so the `first` function is perhaps misleadingly named. It returns the *first non-null value that it finds for that column* i.e. pretty much any non-null value for that column within the group.

Sorting your rows before the `groupBy` doesn't affect the order within the group in any reproducible way.

See also this [blog post](https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/be-careful-with-first/) which explains that, because of the behaviour above, the values you get from multiple `first` calls may not even be from the same row within the group.

> Input data with 3 column “k, t, v”

```
z, 1, null
z, 2, 1.5
z, 3, 2.4
```

> Code:

```
df.groupBy("k").agg(
  $"k",
  first($"t"),
  first($"v")
)
```

> Output:

```
z, 1, 1.5
```

> This result is a mix of 2 records!